# Differential equations : A tank contains 1000 L of brine

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

A tank contains 1000 L of brine (that is, salt water) with 15 kg of dissolved salt.

Pure water enters the top of the tank at a constant rate of 10 L / min.

The solution is thoroughly mixed and drains from the bottom of the tank at the same rate so that the volume of liquid in the tank is constant.

Questions:

a) Find a differential equation expressing the rate at which salt leaves the tank.

b) Solve this differential equation to find an expression for the amount of salt (in kg) in the mixture at time t.

c) How long does it take for the total amount of salt in the brine to be reduced by half its original amount? (Recall ln 2 ≈ .693.)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I'm a beginner in the field, I couldn't manage to come with an idea.

Comment: Please show your attempts. Your question appears to be a copy-and-pasted homework problem. Did you learn something in lecture or a textbook which would help you solve problem (a)? Can you write down something to start?

Comment: It is not homework, this question appears in the MIT OCW scholar course for 18.01 single variable calculus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hardest part to this exercise is setting up the equation. Salt flows out of the tank at a rate of

$$\left(\frac S{1000}\frac{\rm kg}{\rm L}\right)\left(10\dfrac{\rm L}{\rm min}\right)=\frac S{100}\frac{\rm kg}{\rm min}$$

That is, the salt content changes based on the concentration of salt in the tank (which is the amount of salt per unit volume) multiplied by the rate at which the mixture is getting drained.

So the net rate of change of the salt content, $S$, is governed by the differential equation,

$$S'=-\frac S{100}\iff S'+\frac S{100}=0$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: yes thank you for your help I appreciate that.